# Index Firestore multiple values

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

imagine I have an array that looks like this

```
postedAt: 241242
categories:
- gaming: true
- history: true
- sports: true
```

Is it possible to create firestore index that looks something like this...

categories.* descending: true

Or do I have to create an index for every possible value inside categories?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. [Use Subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/structure-data).

```
let data: [String: Any] = [
    "postedAt": 241242,
    "categories": [
        "gaming": true,
        "history": true,
        "sports": true,
    ]
]

Firestore.firestore().collection("users/data").addDocument(data)
```